# Yii2 - Model is not saving in foreach loop in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a variable

I have run foreach loop for every item

```
$tags = ['#first_Tag','#second_tag','#third_tag','#fourth_Tag'];
foreach ($tags as $t) :

  $model = new Tags;

  $model->tag_name = $t;

  $model->save(); //yii2

endforeach;
```

this function only saves the last item which is #fourth_Tag.
Can any one have solution about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show `Tags` model code.

Comment: `$model->save()` should return true if model has been saved, false otherwise. Test for it and if it returns false, do `print_r($model->errors)` to see what is wrong.

Comment: I haved used this problem and it worked correctly..... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered exactly same problem and got perfect solution. This is tested.

```
$tags = ['#first_Tag','#second_tag','#third_tag','#fourth_Tag'];
foreach ($tags as $t) :

  $model = new Tags;

  $model->tag_name = $t;

  $model->save(); //yii2

  unset($model);

endforeach;
```

This is when you make a new variable with the same name of existing one, it overwrite its value. Here you don't need to make new attribute or set id to `null`; just `unset()` `$model` before the end of `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

```
$tags = ['#first_Tag','#second_tag','#third_tag','#fourth_Tag'];
$model = new Tags;

foreach ($tags as $t) :

  $model->id = NULL; //primary key(auto increment id) id
  $model->isNewRecord = true;
  $model->tag_name = $t;

  $model->save(); //yii2

endforeach;
```

Comment: hai gamitg I tried your code..itz really working..but itz create an extra filed in my DB.Can you say Y itz happend???

Comment: its do not create extra field but it creates new row for new record.